# Need to get response json from the api call

Tags: javascript, java, web-services

I am trying to hit the below service which has multiple get calls I need to extraxt json from embeded get calls

I am hitting the below url www.barchart.com
Please hit below url go to network to see multiple get calls being called and generating response
www.barchart.com

Its internally calling below get method
https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?fields=symbol%2CsymbolName%2CsymbolType%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2CpriceVolume%2CtradeTime%2CsymbolCode&orderBy=priceVolume&orderDir=desc&limit=10&lists=stocks.volumeLeaders.price-volume.etf&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description&raw=1

I need to get the response of this. Please help me to find the url which produces that reponse.

I have tried hitting the get request its giving 500 internal error. I think i am missing something I am hitting the get service inside the service. Please help me figure out how to solve internal calling in web services.

Comment: please post the code you use to hit the API, to the question

Answer (score 0):

You must first specify what are the parameters you are passing in the URL for example
https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?fields=symbol=?&CsymbolName=?&CsymbolType=?&ClastPrice=?&CpriceChange=?&CpercentChange=?&CpriceVolume=?&CtradeTime=?&CsymbolCode=?&orderBy=priceVolume=?&orderDir=desc&limit=10&lists=stocks.volumeLeaders.price-volume.etf&meta=field.shortName&Cfield.type&Cfield.description&raw=1

It will set the parameters to URL 
You can retrieve by using the $_REQUEST 
ex. $_REQUEST['CpriceVolume'] in PHP 
Similarly in other FrameWorks & Language

Comment: run the query and set the parameters

Comment: echo the result in json_encode($result) it will done the trick